# Is it possible to generalize this code in one single place?

Tags: c#

I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

All my domain models include the `GroupId` property. A user is assigned a `GroupId`, and when he creates an entity, his `GroupId` is saved with the entity. The user can only perform CRUD operations on those entities that have his `GroupId`.

So currently, at my service layer and based on the `PredicateBuilder` extension, I have a method that adds the `GroupId` when loading an entity:

```
public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where)
{
    var addGroup = groupRepository.Get(EntityType.Customer).AddGroup;
    if (addGroup)
        where = where.And(x => x.GroupId == user.GroupId);

    return customerRepository.Get(where);
}
```

Every `Get` method does the above.

Is there a way to centralize the above code in one place instead of have to repeat the code in each and every `Get` method of all the services I have?

Comment: Are they able to inherit from a base entity?

Comment: @Sayse Only if EF Code-First allows TPH in the above situation

Comment: I'm afraid I dont know enough about Code-First or what TPH is to know the answer if it allows it... my idea was to use a generic base class... [See Example](https://ideone.com/EPx860)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All my domain models include the GroupId property

Then all your domain models should implement an interface (let's call it `IHasGroup`) that defines the `GroupId` property.

Then, factoring out your code should be easy:

```
public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where)
{
    return GetHelper(EntityType.Customer, where, customerRepository.Get);
}

public static T GetHelper<T>(EntityType type, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, 
                             Func<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, T> repositoryAccessor) 
    where T : IHasGroup
{
    var addGroup = groupRepository.Get(type).AddGroup;
    if (addGroup)
        where = where.And(x => x.GroupId == user.GroupId);

    return repositoryAccessor(where);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following exception: `Unable to cast the type 'Customer' to type 'IHasGroup'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Comment: Ok solved it. Just added the `class` constraint and it works fine.

Comment: This is a common problem.If you use an interface, you cannot use this in a Linq query because Entity Framework does not know about this property. If you want to do this, you would need to have all your entities inheriting from the same base entity which is most probably a big no-no...

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an interface.

```
public interface IGroup
{
 int GroupId {get; set;}
}
```

then update your method to work with the interface:

```
public IGroup Get(Expression<Func<IGroup, bool>> where)
{
    var addGroup = groupRepository.Get(EntityType.Customer).AddGroup;
    if (addGroup)
        where = where.And(x => x.GroupId == user.GroupId);

    return customerRepository.Get(where);
}
```

Pass customerRepository and entity type as parameters. You may need to extract base interfaces/classes for them as well.

If you cannot change the return type then extract this part in another method:

```
 var addGroup = groupRepository.Get(EntityType.Customer).AddGroup;
    if (addGroup)
        where = where.And(x => x.GroupId == user.GroupId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your customerRepository in a user specific customerRepository, like

```
public class UserSpecificCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository{
 private User _user;
 private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

 public UserSpecificCustomerRepository(User user, ICustomerRepository repo){
   _user = user;
   _customerRepository = repo;
 }

 public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where){
   where = where.And(x => x.GroupId == _user.GroupId);

  _customerRepository.Get(where);
 }
}
```

Now you have only one place where the expression is extended. Your code would change to

```
public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where)
{
  var addGroup = groupRepository.Get(EntityType.Customer).AddGroup;
  if (addGroup) {
    return new UserSpecificCustomerRepository(user, customerRepository).Get(where);
  }

  return customerRepository.Get(where);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using baseEntity and have some common methods there on base
Then inherit baseEntity in all your entities so you will have common methods for each entity.

```
public class EntityBase<T>
{
    public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        //your Logic here
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
      //Your Logic here
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        //Your Logic here
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.